# Separate a column detail into row

Tags: r

I have a long dataset which is in this below format. How can I have the email id in the `father_details`just besides the name of the father name. Any ideas?

sample data:

```
structure(list(Name = c("John", NA, NA, NA, "Chris", NA, NA, 
NA), Email = c("john@abc.com", NA, NA, NA, "chris@abc.com", NA, 
NA, NA), father_details = c("herald", NA, NA, "herald@abc.com", 
"matthew", NA, NA, "matthew@abc.com")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
8L))
```

```
Name  Email         father_details 
  <chr> <chr>         <chr>          
1 John  john@abc.com  herald         
2 NA    NA            NA             
3 NA    NA            NA             
4 NA    NA            herald@abc.com 
5 Chris chris@abc.com matthew        
6 NA    NA            NA             
7 NA    NA            NA             
8 NA    NA            matthew@abc.com
```

Desired output:

```
  Name  Email         father_details  father_email   
  <chr> <chr>         <chr>           <chr>          
1 John  john@abc.com  herald          herald@abc                
2 Chris chris@abc.com matthew         matthew@abc.com
```

Comment: please add the desired output structure

Answer (score 1):

## base R

```r
quux <- within(quux, {
  father_email <- ave(father_details, cumsum(!is.na(Name)),
                      FUN = function(y) { z <- na.omit(y); c(z[length(z)], rep(NA, length(y)-1)); });
  father_details <- ifelse(is.na(father_email), NA, father_details);
})
quux
#    Name         Email father_details    father_email
# 1  John  john@abc.com         herald  herald@abc.com
# 2  <NA>          <NA>           <NA>            <NA>
# 3  <NA>          <NA>           <NA>            <NA>
# 4  <NA>          <NA>           <NA>            <NA>
# 5 Chris chris@abc.com        matthew matthew@abc.com
# 6  <NA>          <NA>           <NA>            <NA>
# 7  <NA>          <NA>           <NA>            <NA>
# 8  <NA>          <NA>           <NA>            <NA>
quux[complete.cases(quux),]
#    Name         Email father_details    father_email
# 1  John  john@abc.com         herald  herald@abc.com
# 5 Chris chris@abc.com        matthew matthew@abc.com
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(!is.na(Name))) %>%
  summarize(
    Name = na.omit(Name), Email = na.omit(Email),
    father_email = grep("@", na.omit(father_details), value = TRUE)[1],
    father_details = grep("@", na.omit(father_details), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  select(-grp)
# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#   Name  Email         father_email    father_details
#   <chr> <chr>         <chr>           <chr>         
# 1 John  john@abc.com  herald@abc.com  herald        
# 2 Chris chris@abc.com matthew@abc.com matthew
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `dplyr` and `fill` function from `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  fill(Name) %>%
  mutate(father_email = if_else(grepl('@', father_details), 
                                father_details, NA_character_)) %>%
  summarise(across(Email:father_email, ~na.omit(.)[1]), .by = Name)

#   Name         Email father_details    father_email
#1  John  john@abc.com         herald  herald@abc.com
#2 Chris chris@abc.com        matthew matthew@abc.com
```

`father_email` column is filled with `father_details` value if it has `@` in it. Each `Name` is collapsed into a single row by taking 1st non-NA value from it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively please check

base r

```r
name <- df$Name[which(!is.na(df$Name))]
email <- df$Email[which(!is.na(df$Email))]
father_name1 <- df$father_details[which(!is.na(df$father_details))]
father_name <- father_name1[which(!grepl('\\@',father_name1))]
father_email <- father_name1[which(grepl('\\@',father_name1))]

df2 <- cbind(name,email,father_name,father_email) %>% as.data.frame()
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
   name         email father_name    father_email
1  John  john@abc.com      herald  herald@abc.com
2 Chris chris@abc.com     matthew matthew@abc.com
```